# How to get a return value in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to get the return value? Attach my code. My intention: Want to check the QListWidget and if it's empty, a  message Box popup will raise and ask the option from the user. **Problem**: At the stage of beginning itself, a Message box popup will display, (I don't want it at the beginning stage), If the QListwidget is empty then the MessageBox popup will display as desired, and if we select "Yes" or " No" Button, Nothing will return/print in the first file. How to resolve?

**Main**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QListWidget,QVBoxLayout,QLineEdit
from msgbox_secondfile import *

class MsgBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Msgbox")

        self.textbox = QLineEdit()
        self.listbox = QListWidget()
        self.listbox.addItems(["item001","item002","Gold Fish"])
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.textbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.listbox)

        self.getdetails_1 = Msgbox_002(self.textbox, self.listbox)
        self.textbox.textChanged.connect(self.getdetails_1.func_textbox_textchanged)

        # Here,I need a retun value from  Method "func_create_newitem, I try the follwing code
        # This code make a 2 problems,
        # first problem : At beggning itself, msg box will displayed, I dont want at beggning
        # second: after click the "yes" or "No" button from msg box, nothing will print here

        new = Msgbox_002.func_create_newitem(self)
        print("retun value print :",new)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MsgBox()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Second**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QMessageBox,QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Msgbox_002(QWidget) :
    def __init__(self, tb,lb):
        super().__init__()
        self.textbox = tb
        self.listbox = lb


    def func_textbox_textchanged(self):
        self.item_contains = self.listbox.findItems(self.textbox.text(), Qt.MatchContains)

        if len(self.item_contains) == 0 :
            self.func_create_newitem()


    def func_create_newitem(self):
        self.msgBox = QMessageBox()
        self.msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        self.msgBox.setText("Item Not found.... Create a new One" )
        self.msgBox.setWindowTitle("QMessageBox Example")
        self.msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        self.returnValue = self.msgBox.exec_()
        

        if self.msgBox.clickedButton() is self.msgBox.button(QMessageBox.Yes):
            print("Yes button clicked")
            self.ss = " ok button cliked from return"
            return self.ss
        if self.msgBox.clickedButton() is self.msgBox.button(QMessageBox.No):
            # print("No Button Clicked")
            self.ss = "cancle button clicked from return"
            return self.ss
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, if we correct the obvious error then the QMessageBox will be displayed every time the user types a new letter. Could you explain the operation in more detail, for example, let's say the user presses "i" then what should happen? and if you press "a" then what should happen?

Comment: sir, I want to create a new item if not found in Qlistwidget. So I check it is empty or not. If  Qlistwidget is empty, then  message box will pop up and shows the message, "Item not found, want to create one.." and options button are "Yes" and " No", If I press "Yes" button then do something if I Press "No" button , focus to textbox. @eyllanesc

Comment: Even your question is not clear, according to your code the QListWidget has 3 elements: `"item001", "item002" and "Gold Fish"` let's say the user presses the letter "a" then in that specific case what should happen? Please answer my specific question, the same if the letter "i" is pressed.

Comment: if press a, item not found. length of the fitem is empty( len(self.item_contains)==0), message box will popup and return the vale to main file

Comment: If the letter "i" is pressed instead then what should happen?

Comment: check my Qlistwidget with textbox, if item not found, then i want to disply messaage box, if   I Press button reference value is pass to the main file.

Comment: Please answer my specific questions as I want to understand your request or otherwise point out the logical error that you may have

Comment: if we pree "I" then item001 and item 002 is found . I checki it with  "self.item_contains = self.listbox.findItems(self.textbox.text(), Qt.MatchContains)" if its equal to zero then message box will display and ask options

Comment: Okay, I already understood your logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first it is not necessary to make the verification be done in a new class, it is also logical that you invoke func_create_newitem since as you point out that method must be invoked when the item was not found.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit

from msgbox_secondfile import MessageBox


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Msgbox")

        self.textbox = QLineEdit()
        self.listbox = QListWidget()
        self.listbox.addItems(["item001", "item002", "Gold Fish"])

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textbox)
        vbox.addWidget(self.listbox)

        self.msgbox = MessageBox()

        self.textbox.textChanged.connect(self.handle_text_changed)

    def handle_text_changed(self):
        text = self.textbox.text()
        if not text:
            return
        items = self.listbox.findItems(text, Qt.MatchContains)
        if not items:
            res = self.msgbox.execute()
            print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Widget()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


class MessageBox(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        self.setText("Item Not found.... Create a new One")
        self.setWindowTitle("QMessageBox Example")
        self.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)

    def execute(self):
        self.exec_()
        if self.clickedButton() is self.button(QMessageBox.Yes):
            return " ok button cliked from return"
        elif self.clickedButton() is self.button(QMessageBox.No):
            return "cancel button clicked from return"
        return "not button clicked"
```

Comment: sir, it's work, But it does not satisfy my need.  My requirement is if we pass a reference from the first file to the second file. That is Passing  a value from first file (textbox value, list box value ) is processed in the second file  and get the processed result from second file to first file@eyllanesc

Comment: @tckraomuqnt This approach is wrong since you are making a class have more responsibilities than it should handle. I recommend you read the Single-responsibility principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

Comment: Sir. In my main script, I do a lot of processing in the second file itself (like keypressevent, mouse press event, change focus from textbox to list box, etc)  And also I Want to do the same process for multiple text boxes. So I need anyone signal from the second file to the first file. Please don't bother about the message box. Pls suggest how to transfer any signals from  the second file to the first one, if the item is not found